# Laravel Pivot model with extra attributes

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, pivot-table

I've got Item catalog management system.

**CatalogItem**(model):

```
 Schema::create('catalog_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->float('price');
        $table->float('deposit')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Pricing**(model):

```
 Schema::create('pricings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name',127);
        $table->boolean('enable')->default(true);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**CatalogItemPricingPivot**(pivot model):

```
Schema::create('catalog_item_pricing', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->bigInteger('catalog_item_id');
        $table->bigInteger('pricing_id');
        $table->float('discount')->nullable()->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Now when I want to update pricing for CatalogItem I do this:

```
$CatalogItem->pricings()->sync([
    1 => array:1 [
        "discount" => "25.00"
    ]
]);
```

This also could be

```
 $CatalogItem->pricings()->sync([
    1 => array:1 [
        "discount" => "25.00"
    ],
    5 => array:1 [
        "discount" => "12.25"
    ]
]);
```

if I'm printing model in observer I don't get the discount field in originals

```
 public function boot()
{

    CatalogItemPricingPivot::updated(function($model){
        dd($model);
    });
}
```

result

```
App\Pivots\CatalogItemPricingPivot {
  table: "catalog_item_pricing"
  exists: true
  wasRecentlyCreated: false
  attributes: array:4 [
    "catalog_item_id" => 172
    "pricing_id" => 1
    "discount" => "25.00"
  ]
  original: array:2 [
    "catalog_item_id" => 172
    "pricing_id" => 1
  ]
  changes: array:2 [
    "discount" => "25.00"
  ]
  casts: []
}
```

and it seems like it change bit its not.

How can I get real change for pivot table with extra field after sync ?

***EDIT:***

The **MAIN** purpose is to get CatalogItemPricingPivot that where updated

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To update already attached pivot data you should use `updateExistingPivot` method.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Instead of

```
$CatalogItem->pricings()->sync([
    1 => array:1 [
        "discount" => "25.00"
    ]
]);
```

try this

```
$CatalogItem->pricings()->each(function ($pricing) use ($CatalogItem) {
    $CatalogItem->pricings()->updateExistingPivot($pricing, [
        "discount" => "23.00"
    ]);
});
```

Comment: what about new pivot ?

Comment: Yes but I'm also using sync to detach

Comment: So I need both cases , first sync and then updateExistingPivot

Comment: after the each how can I know if pivot table changed ?

Answer (score 0):

Saw your post on upwork.

try adding `->withPivot('discount');` to the relationship

Comment: there is 
$this->belongsToMany(Pricing::class)
            ->using(CatalogItemPricingPivot::class)
            ->withPivot('discount')
            ->withTimestamps();